# Mysql data in a tooltip

Tags: mysql, tooltip

I´m using the tooltip script [qtip2](http://qtip2.com/). I want to show inside the tooltip informations from a Mysql database.

For that im using a **ajax.php**

```
    $var = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['var']);

//connection to the database
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect($localhost, $XXXXX, $XXXX)
      or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    //select a database to work with
    $selected = mysql_select_db("tester",$dbhandle)
      or die("Could not select examples");

    //execute the SQL query and return records
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT information FROM data_table WHERE value='$var'");
    //fetch tha data from the database
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
       echo $row{'Name'};
       echo $row{'Beschreibung'};
    }

    //close the connection

    mysql_close($dbhandle);
```

And the **test.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Test</title>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.1.0/jquery.qtip.min.css" />

        <!-- /stylings -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/qtip2/2.1.0/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
        <!-- /scripts -->

    </head>
    <body>

        <a href="test/ajax.php" class="ajax_TT">
        Enterprise hosting</a>

        <script type="text/javascript">

           $(function () {
    $(".ajax_TT").on("click",function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // normalized for IE
        var $this=$(this);
        var link = $this.attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            cache: false,
            data: {
                html: "<p>Text echoed back to request</p>"
            },
            method: 'post'
        }).done(function (html) {
            $this.qtip({
                content: {
                    text: html
                },
                style: 'qtip-wiki',
                show: {
                  ready: true
                }
            });
        });
    });
});

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

On the test.html everything works, but if i use the test.html code inside a Joomla article, the tooltip just show the code from the ajax.php, and not the Mysql data.

Here is a screenshot, how it looks like in a Joomla article.

(http://s14.directupload.net/images/130810/8dicx7la.jpg)

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Joomla is escaping the PHP code. I'm guessing the file is in the same directory as Joomla. Try moving the PHPfile outside of Joomla.

If you are on CPanel, you could probably create a different subdomain that would still have access to the DB. Another alternative is to use a Joomla plugin that allows you to execute PHP code like the following but I'm not sure how that would work out.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/custom-code-in-content/4470

I'm not a Joomla expert but hopefully that points you in the right direction.